# Instagram API возвращает пустой json (null)

Tags: php, api, instagram

Запросы (endpoints):

`method: "GET"
apiCall: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{id}/relationship?access_token=my.validAccess.token"
paramString: null`

`method: "POST"
apiCall: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{id}/relationship?access_token=my.validAccess.token"
paramString: "&action=follow"`

Ответы (через PHP json_decode):

`null`

`null`

(никаких data[], meta, только null)

В то же время, GET-запрос к https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=my.validAccess.token&count=20 возвращает нормальную информацию

Статус приложения - sandbox. Юзер, который авторизовался - тоже в sandbox. Права - все: ['basic', 'public_content', 'follower_list', 'comments', 'relationships', 'likes']

Comment: а где запись в документации что это должно что-то возвращать? ссылку дайте.

Comment: такое ощущение что я уже читал этот вопрос на днях

Comment: @teran https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391420/the-instagram-api-will-return-an-empty-json-null

Comment: @E_p не, на нашем СО видел. мб закрыли, не помню на каком языке было написано

Comment: @teran, тема с инстой все чаще появляется на ruSO

Comment: автор, а вы уверены что данный метод работает вообще?

Comment: @DaemonHK, уверен. /users/self/media/recent отдаёт корректные данные. Все endpoints совпадают с документацией

Comment: @NewEXE я не про `media`,  а про `relationship`, который вы используете

Comment: @DaemonHK, GET к `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{id}/relationship` должен возвратить что-то вроде
`{
    "data": {
        "outgoing_status": "none",
        "incoming_status": "requested_by"
    }
}`
если передать неправильный id, то выдаст ошибку, с правильным - null

Comment: @NewEXE странно, наобум под левыми токеном и пользователем через браузер постучался по данной ссылке, вернулся json  с 400 ошибкой, то есть все работает, может вы не правильно данные пытаетесь получить? И кстати, в GET запросе токен обязателен. А вы уверены что у пользователя есть такие данные (друзья, фоловверы)?

Comment: @DaemonHK, в этом-то и проблема, 400 ошибка возвращается, когда передать неверный id (почитайте возвращенное описание ошибки). Когда верный - ошибки нет, null. Похоже на недоработку API, когда меня не сочли нужным даже проинформировать об ошибке. Друзья, фоловверы есть

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69048/discussion-between-newexe-and-daemonhk).

Comment: @Jean-Claude, https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_relationship